# JTable Tooltip from sql?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtooltip

I have been bugging with this for 2 days now. I have a `JTable` that is being generated with SQL from two tables.

The thing is I now need to get a `Mouseover` tooltip to work, with specific information from one of the tables. And its not working.

```
public class Ausgabe extends JPanel {

    public JPanel panel1;
    private Point hintCell;

    Main j;

    MA ali = new MA();

    public Ausgabe(Main j) {
        this.j = j;

    }

    public void createDefault (){
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout( null );

        JLabel lblDieseMitarbeiterSind = new JLabel("Diese Mitarbeiter sind Heute abwesend.");
        lblDieseMitarbeiterSind.setBounds(10, 11, 239, 14);
        panel1.add(lblDieseMitarbeiterSind);

        panel1.add(getHeute());
    }
    public JTable getHeute(){

            DBconnect verbinden = new DBconnect();
            verbinden.erstelleVerbindung();

            JTable Habwesend=new JTable();
            Habwesend.setBounds(10, 30, 200, 400);
            Habwesend.setEnabled(false);
            DefaultTableModel dm=new DefaultTableModel();

            try {
            ResultSet rs= verbinden.sqlStatement.executeQuery("select Vor, Nach from MA_Tabelle where MA_ID in (select distinct MA_ID from AB_Spanne where(Date() >= Start and Date() <= Ende)) ");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
            //Coding to get columns-
            int cols=rsmd.getColumnCount();
            String c[]=new String[cols];
            for(int i=0;i<cols;i++){
                c[i]=rsmd.getColumnName(i+1);
                for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
                    dm.addColumn(c[k]);
                }


            }
            Object row[]=new Object[cols];
            while(rs.next()){
                for(int i=0;i<cols;i++){
                        row[i]=rs.getString(i+1);
                    }
                dm.addRow(row);

            }

            Habwesend.setModel(dm);
            Habwesend.setToolTipText(getToolTipText((MouseEvent) verbinden.sqlStatement.executeQuery("select Start, Ende from AB_Spanne where MA_ID = "+rs)));
            verbinden.schliesseVerbindung();


            }catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println("this failed");
                System.out.print(e);
            }
            return Habwesend;
        }

    public String result() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you set the single tooltip text for the whole table so it is the same for all cells.

Instead, use the custom table class derived from `JTable` and override the method

```
@Override
public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
    Point where = e.getPoint();
    int column = columnAtPoint(where);
    int row = rowAtPoint(where);

    // now run your SQL to get the tooltip text
    ...
    return tooltip;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, I will try to make it work. I am just learning java, so firt I have to make sense of what you actually mean ;)

Comment: +1 but I would suggest to get all tooltips in one query and store them in the model somewhere, instead of querying each time in `getToolTipText()`

Answer (score 1):

The `JTable` respects the tooltip text set on the renderer. No need to override the `getToolTipText` of the `JTable`.

Use a renderer in which you specify the tooltip. I however highly discourage you to run SQL queries in the renderer as this will slow down your application. Typically, database queries are done on a background thread, and the results are fed into your model, at which point you update the view. Consult the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial for more information